# calling java.lang.Math.log does not go through the method in debug mode in Eclipse

Tags: java, debugging, math, static, breakpoints

I just started profiling an application that does some `log linear` interpolation, and I noticed something strange when calling `Math.log` and `Math.exp` inside each other. The behaviour can be reproduced the following way:

```
public class TestLogExp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double thisdouble = 0d;
    thisdouble = Math.log(Math.exp(10));
    System.out.println(thisdouble);
    }
}
```

Now we clearly see that `Math.log` and `Math.exp` are called within this main method. However, when I put a breakpoint in both `Math.exp` and `Math.log` (which are just calls to `StrictMath` `native statics`), the execution is only interrupted in `Math.exp`, not in `Math.log`.

Now I thought it could be that `java` does not debug calls within calls from static methods, but when I call `Math.exp(Math.log(10))` (so the other way around), the same behaviour is observed, only stopping in exp, not in log...

Anybody able to reproduce this? Why is this happening?

**EDIT:** It seems like it's not debugging the Math.log function at all. Replace the line `thisdouble = Math.log(Math.exp(10));` with `thisdouble = Math.log(10);`, and still not stopping in debug mode, although there's a breakpoint in Math.class...

Comment: I was able to reproduce it. Very weird. It might be because StrictMath uses `native` methods. Just break up your code a little bit, and debug line by line...

Comment: Wouldn't that just be optimized out since the answer is `10.0` ?

Comment: No, check my edit, apparently even just a call to `Math.log` on it's own does not go through `Math.log` in debug mode...

Comment: @vikingsteve the fact that StrictMath uses natives doesn't mean that the execution shouldn't go through Math.log...

Comment: You would think so, but something is amiss...

Comment: Yes, but why does it work for `Math.exp` then? Which is also a native call...

Answer (score 0):

It does go into both the methods if you try it this way:

```
    Double thisdouble = 0d;
    double temp = Math.exp(10);
    thisdouble = Math.log(temp);
    System.out.println(thisdouble);
```

I am using Netbeans v7.3

Comment: Thanks, can you check just `thisdouble = Math.log(10)`? See if there he goes through Math.log? Because I'm using Eclipse, and your example doesn't stop in Math.log for me either... So could be an eclipse-related problem...